# Scala function declaration: placeholder vs parameter?

Tags: scala

Why does the following work only using the format **a => xxx** to define a function?

```
Some("Help").foreach(p => println(p + " me"))
```

will produce the output "Help me", which is what I expect.   On the other hand, the following code (which I see as equivalent)

```
Some("Help").foreach(println(_ + " me"))
```

results in an error at the underscore: 
*missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1: ) => x$1.$plus(" me"))*.

But the following (very similar)

```
Some("Help").foreach(println(_))
```

results in "Help" which is also the expected behavior.

In a 3rd attempt, I tried to specify the type, like this:

```
Some("Help").foreach(println((_: String) + " me"))
```

and the result was 
*error: type mismatch;* 
*found   : Unit;*
*required: String => ?*

So, what is going on?  Why doesn't the underscore syntax work?

Comment: I edited the question to indicate how this is NOT a duplicate of the question you refer it to.  They are 2 different questions.  One is about why some syntax is not working.  The other is about showing generic uses of the same type of syntax.

Comment: I think scala turns the `_` into a partially applied function and then feeds the context to it so the second and forth cases can't be converted and thats why they fail

Comment: Thanks, Mr. D.   I think I understand the difference now, and it is indeed a duplicate question as Yuval pointed out.  I'm new to scala.   When I use "println( _ )"  the underscore is parameter substitution.   But when I say "println(_ + " me")" it's no longer parameter substitution.  The expression  _ + "me" is now the definition of a function.